# File Path in WebClient

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net application, I am writing a file in code behind. I then want to use this file as below into a Handler but I get an error 'Illegal characters in Path'. I can't understand why? Help please.

The value of files in below is "306963020170816111848_Generic_P.pdf" and the file definitely exists in the correct path

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 client.DownloadString(@"Handlers/MyPrintPdf.ashx?PdfFile=" + Server.MapPath("~/Templates/MyFiles/" + files)); // error here
```

Changed to use

```
  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(@"Handlers/MyPrintPdf.ashx?PdfFile=" + Server.MapPath("~/Templates/MyFiles/" + files));
```

Comment: what is the value of files string?

Comment: its 306963020170816111848_Generic_P.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `Uri` overload of your `DownloadString` method. These parameters must be url encoded.

**EDIT:**
`HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url)`should also work.

Comment: Could you please explain with two lines of code/ example?

Comment: if you put a string like `http://test?hello world !` in your browsers url bar, the string is turned into `http://test/?hello%20world%20!` automatically (tested on chrome). This is a valid format to pass parameters over the URL. You need this behavior also on you webclient (which is not automatically encode your url), so you can use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(yourUrl)` to escape special characters.

Comment: Thanks that works. But why does not go into my handler's ProcessRequest code?

Comment: Then please accept as answer. Can you show me some example code?